# Are there any female lycans?

Tags: werewolf, underworld

From watching the first Underworld movie, I didn't see any females who were lycans. It looked like about half of the vampires were females, but apparently all of the lycans were male. Is there any in-universe explanation for this? Or if not, is there an out-of-universe explanation?

I don't know whether the other three movies have female Lycans, but it seems that they don't exist or at least don't appear on screen during the first movie. Of course, the plot didn't require any female lycans, but I didn't see any women in the background of the lycans' den either.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not in the movies but in Underworld universe they do have female lycans, before Rise of the Lycan came out, in the novel **Blood Enemy** there are several female lycans that play a huge role in the story.

[Grushenka](http://underworld.wikia.com/wiki/Grushenka_(Blood_Enemy)) is a character in the non-canon novel Blood Enemy. She is a Lycan who works as a laundress for the Vampires. Grushenka does not exist in the official canon of the Underworld series.

Also there is an Underworld anime film that delves in the distant past, the near past and the present day with Selene hunting three Delta Lycan brothers. One of the brothers has a harem/pack full of female lycans for his pleasure and reproducing. It's called: [Underworld Endless War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underworld:_Endless_War).

Per Wiki of endless War in [Part III](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Underworld:_Endless_War#Part_III):

> Michael's attempt to take Krandrill by surprise is foiled when Krandrill picks up on Michael's scent first, and Michael hears howling, all before Selene can meet him there, as she has to deal with the IPU men (who also heard the howling). Michael crashes through the entrance, only to be taken by surprise himself by Krandrill (already in werewolf form), and his harem of female Lycans (all of whom are armed), and transforms into his hybrid form

Comment: Also in the noviilisation of the first film females were mentioned.

Answer (score 3):

*Underworld: Blood Wars* has female lycans. Besides women being listed in the cast as lycans on the film’s [IMDb page](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt3717252/), Kate Beckinsale said this in a [Q&A about *Blood Wars* on Facebook](https://www.facebook.com/UnderworldMovie/videos/1527225717303579/) (7 minutes into the video):

> **Question**: *Will there be any female lycans?*
>   **Kate Beckinsale**: Well, here’s the thing: the advantage of having a female director is that she was quite concerned about the whole fact that the female lycans always seemed to be at home making dinner and not actually on screen. So yes, there are female lycans, and we had some quite fun days of a lot of naked people. Because when they die they turn back into naked humans. So it was a very equal-opportunity naked situation in Prague, which I was very happy about.

Comment: Incidentally, the "equal-opportunity naked situation" mentioned by Beckinsale seems to have been cut from the film.

Answer (score 2):

I just assumed it was because they didn't want naked women on the screen (since every lycan seems to rip off their shirt while transforming). Because secondary sexual characteristics are bad when they aren't beards. :)

I'd hate the idea of female lycan staying home though, I hope that never shows up.

This was also an interesting series where the guys couldn't keep their shirts on but a lot of the women had high collars and covered up completely. It was a nice difference from the other movies at the time (of the first one).

Comment: Yeah, that’s probably why there weren’t any female lycans before. But apparently, this new director wasn’t convinced that non-beard secondary sexual characteristics are bad. :p